# android dev: problem with mobile internet connection after phone wake up

Tags: android

I've encountered a problem with mobile internet connection after phone wake up from sleep mode. There is an application which updates some data periodically. `AlarmManager` triggers my `BroadcastReceiver` which starts `service`. `service` acquires `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` and some http requests are sent. Unfortunately when update interval is quite big (5h) `service` could not send/download anything. Problem doesn't appear when I'm using WIFI connection instead of mobile and `WIFI sleep policy` is set to `never`. Everything is OK on mobile connection when update interval is short (less than half an hour). I'm also sure 5h event is received by my `BroadcastReceiver` because I've checked it.

How such events should be handled. I've tried to check whether connection is established by `ConnectivityManager` and retry 5 times if not but still same problem appears.

Thanks for any answer in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Android system turns of WiFi a few minutes when the device is suspended (i.e. screen turned off).
When the device turns on again (by acquiring the wake-lock), it will take a few seconds until network connection is re-established (this is also true for 3G data connections, which are also torn-down while device is sleeping).

My suggestion:
- Wait for ConnectivityManager's broadcast that the network is up again. Practice proves that waiting 2-3 seconds after the broadcast is received helps things to settle before starting to send and receive data.
- A bit easier: After grabbing the wake-lock, wait a longer timeout and then try to connect.

Comment: Where should I acquire wake-lock? Inside `AlarmReceiver` and pass to `Service` or directly in `service`?

Comment: Better in the AlarmReceiver - as depending on how you pass control to the service (e.g. by sending an intent), the system could go to sleep again.

Comment: by `Intent`, I don't know other way. So in case of intent, how should I pass it to `service`. I've read on Stack most often it is done by static variable inside `service`. Can it be done better?

Comment: A static variable inside the service seems like a good solution to me.

Comment: could you describe more suggestion with ConnectivityManager broadcast receiver? If I understood you correctly, AlarmManager receiver should register additional receiver (for ConnectivityManager). How wake lock should be handled then? I can't acquire it inside AM broadcast receiver and release inside service started by CM broadcast receiver because it can happen connection won't be established (caused by lack of signal). Lock won't be released. It leads to battery drain.